# Resposive Google Maps javascript api turns out grey (sometimes)

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I have two websites which attempt to display a map of bushfires in an area, using the Google Maps javascript api and a GeoJson from the NSW RFS. Both are resposive sites.
The maps seem very twitchy about displaying the actual map background, and in one case I always get a grey background (though markers etc are properly displayed).

This seems to be related to the way the map canvas is sized; if a fixed width and height are set then all is well, but if % are used grey is displayed. In the one case setting width and height in vw (% of viewport width) works, but in the other it does not.
The site that works is http://lansdowne.rfsa.org.au/firemap.php 
the one that does not is http://www.upperlansdownehall.org.au/firemap/ - if you zoon out to a larger area ytou will see that markers appear in both maps.

The major difference is that one is Wordpress, with the javascript enqueued with the footer, while the other is imbedded in the html.

I have tried setting the size (width and height) of the map-canvas in js (or that of an enclosing division) using the following code either in the initilize routine or just before the addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

```
var mw = document.getElementById('map-canvasout').offsetWidth;
var mw = document.documentElement.clientWidth * .5; 
var mh = mw * .75;
var mhx = mh + "px";
var mapara = document.getElementById('map-canvasout');
mapara.style.height= mhx;
```

I would be very grateful for any ideas, as I am out of them. code for the wordpress scripts encode and js follows:-

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ulmh_googlemaps', 105);

```
function ulmh_googlemaps(){
    if (is_page('32') || is_page('233')) {
    wp_register_script( 'gmap', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBAlriyR-tmJU4jrd0z9nmWEmw4XSS0nC0',true);
    wp_register_script( 'ulmh_gmap', plugins_url( 'firemap.js', __FILE__ ),true);
    wp_enqueue_script('gmap');
    wp_enqueue_script('ulmh_gmap');
    }
}

function initialize() {
var lat = -31.71    ;
var lng = 152.47;
var zom = 12;
var nam = "Upper Lansdowne";
var mapOptions = {
center: { lat: lat, lng: lng},
zoom: zom
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
map.data.loadGeoJson('http://www.upperlansdownehall.org.au/wp-content/uploads/majorIncidents.json');
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
var IconBase = 'http://www.rfs.nsw.gov.au/_designs/geojson/fires-near-me/images/';
var image = {
url: IconBase + 'watch-and-act.png',
size: new google.maps.Size(27, 27),
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
anchor: new google.maps.Point(14, 13)
};
var ctg = feature.getProperty('category');
switch (ctg) {
case "Emergency Warning": image.url = IconBase + 'emergency-warning.png'; break;
case "Watch and Act": image.url = IconBase + 'watch-and-act.png'; break;
case "Advice": image.url = IconBase + 'advice.png'; break;
default: image.url = IconBase + 'not-applicable.png';
}
return {
icon: image
};
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
var ef = event.feature;
var myHTML = '<b>'+ef.getProperty("title") + '</b></br>' + ef.getProperty("description");
infowindow.setContent("<div style='width:250px;'>"+myHTML+"</div>");
infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,0)});
infowindow.open(map);
});
nam = 'Fire Map of the ' + nam + ' Area';
lat = Math.round(lat*10000)/10000;
lng = Math.round(lng*10000)/10000;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {    // 'bounds_changed'
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
var mapbnd = map.getBounds();
var nbrfre = 0;
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
var geo = feature.getGeometry();
if (geo.getType() == 'Point') {
var LatLng = geo.get();
if (mapbnd.contains(LatLng)) {
nbrfre = nbrfre +1;
}
} else if (geo.getType() == 'GeometryCollection') {
var LatLng = geo.getAt(0).get();
console.log(LatLng);
if (mapbnd.contains(LatLng)) {
nbrfre = nbrfre +1;
}
}
});
var fretxt = ' (No Fires)';
if (nbrfre == 1) {
fretxt = ' (1 Fire)';
} else if (nbrfre > 1) {
fretxt = ' (' + nbrfre + ' Fires)';
}
var ctr = map.getCenter();
clt = Math.round(ctr.lat()*10000)/10000;
cln = Math.round(ctr.lng()*10000)/10000;
if ((clt != lat) || (cln != lng) ||(zom != map.getZoom())) {
nn = 'General Fire Map';
} else {
nn = nam;
}
var pstttl = document.getElementsByClassName("posttitle");
pstttl[0].innerHTML = nn + fretxt;
if (nbrfre != 0) {
pstttl[0].style.backgroundColor='red';
}
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems my unconscious is better at this than the rest of me, as I woke up this morning with a partial answer. One site was using the experimental version of Google Maps (by default) while the other specified v=3 and therefore got the release version.
Of course that raises the question of what is happening at Googles end, but I’ll chase that up with them.
Thanks to anyone who looked at the question.